# "RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout" when using Positioned inside a Stack

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-positioned

I'm creating a widget that presents a `Stack` inside a `Container`. Inside the `Stack` there is a dynamic `Column` inside a `Positioned` widget, which sticks the `Column` to the `Bottom`.

I am trying to wrap the `Stack` in a `SingleChildScrollView`, that if the dynamic `Column` will have lots of children it will be able to scroll.

But after I add the scroll view I get this error message:

`RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scrollView doesn't have height, it will use infinite height for it's children. So the stack should be wrapped in a sizedBox widh a known height in case that you want that. If you want the stack to fill the screen then remove the singleChildScrollview completely. And if you want the stack to be scrollable from the inside. Just add SingleChildScrollView inside the stack

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.blue[100],
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned.fill(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: MyColumn()))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

EDIT 1:
Ok the problem is the layout itself. Since you only use the stack to position the image. And you know the widht and height of the image, and the background shape fills all the items. We could

Isolate the stack only to the image, and use padding and some calculation to have the layout build in a similar way.

Then render everything else inside a normal column

My implementation https://dartpad.dev/230b14d8f0b22b45929a75c208786257

Comment: I have a few additional `Positioned` elements (images etc) that I want them to be scrolled when the `Column` is scrolled, so I need the `scrollView` to wrap the `Stack` itself. How can I make the `Stack` itself scrollable if I don't know the height (because the `Column` is dynamic)?

Comment: Welp, that's quite difficult to figure out when the layout has multiple potential "infinite heighters". I would start by comennting everything else and using only the column. Then set the property mainAxisSize  of the column to MainAxisSize.min .That should be the starting point. From there figure out if other widgets are giving infinite height

Comment: I still get the error when commenting everything except the `Column` and setting the `mainAxisSize` (only when using `Positioned`). Do you know why?

Comment: Oh positioned might be stretching the column even with that. I really don't know where to look since the code is not enough. maybe add a `top:0` to the positioned ?, the problem is not in stack, it is in your content

Comment: I've added the `top: 0` but nothing changed... It happens even when I try to add just a simple `Text` widget inside a `Positioned` instead of the `Column`

Comment: I've edited my question with a bit more detailed information, so maybe now you can see more clearly what I'm trying to achieve. I would appreciate if you will take a look :)

Comment: Check the edited answer, since you only use stack at the top, you could move the stack only to that part and give it a known height

Comment: Thank you very much! You answer helped me a lot

Comment: You are welcome, sometimes the simple way is the best one ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the [`RenderStack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderStack-class.html) documentation:

> First, the non-positioned children (those with null values for top, right, bottom, and left) are laid out and initially placed in the upper-left corner of the stack. The stack is then sized to enclose all of the non-positioned children. If there are no non-positioned children, the stack becomes as large as possible.

Since all of your `Stack`'s children are positioned, `Stack` will match the maximum size constraint passed down by the `SingleChildScrollView`.  This size has infinite height, so the `Stack` is forced to have infinite height as well.

To fix this, you will need to find another way to accomplish what you want.  One option that comes to mind involves a `ConstrainedBox` providing a minimum height (obtained from a `LayoutBuilder`), a non-positioned `Column`, and a `bottomCenter` alignment on the `Stack` itself.  This is similar to the first code sample in the [`SingleChildScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) documentation:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        // This ensures that the Stack fills the entire viewport,
        // even if the Column is small.
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
        ),
        child: Stack(
          // Place the only non-positioned child (the column) at the bottom
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [ /* ... */ ]
            )
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, your explanation of the cause of the problem is very good. Can you please explain a bit more about the proposed solution? Because I did not quite understand it

Comment: I've tried but now I get this error about the `constrainedBox`: `RenderConstrainedBox object was given an infinite size during layout.`

Comment: Did you set the Column's `mainAxisSize`?

Comment: Yes, I did that, to `mainAxisSize.min`

Comment: Do any of the Column's children have infinite height if unconstrained?

Comment: I've edited my question with a bit more detailed information, so maybe now you can see more clearly what I'm trying to achieve. I would appreciate if you will take a look :)